# Ext modules of coherent sheaves and  associated modules

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra, ag.algebraic-geometry

Let $\mathcal{E}$ and $\mathcal{F}$ be two coherent sheaves on a polarized projective variety $(X,\mathcal{O}_X(1))$.

Denote by $E=\Gamma_*(\mathcal{E})=\oplus_{k\in\mathbb{Z}}\mathcal{E}(k)$, 
$F=\Gamma_*(\mathcal{F})$, and  $R= \Gamma_\ast(\mathcal{O}_X)$.

Is it true that
$$\oplus_{k\in\mathbb{Z}}Ext^i_{\mathcal{O}_X}(\mathcal{E}, \mathcal{F}(k))=Ext^i_R(E, F)?$$

If the equality does not hold in general, when and to what extent it will hold?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you mean to ask whether:
$$\oplus_{k\in\mathbb{Z}}Ext^i_{\mathcal{O}_X}(\mathcal{E}, \mathcal{F}(k))=Ext^i_R(E, F)?$$ 
For this question, the answer is no, set $\mathcal{E} = \mathcal{O}_X$.  Choose $\mathcal{F}$ such that $H^i(X, \mathcal{F}) \neq 0$ for some $i > 0$.  Then obviously 
$Ext^i_R(R, F) = 0$.  However $Ext^i_{\mathcal{O}_X}(\mathcal{E}, \mathcal{F}(0)) = H^i(X, \mathcal{F}) \neq 0$.

Comment: What if we assume that $H^i(X, \mathcal{F})=0$ for all $i>0$?

Comment: This example will work as long as some $H^i(X, \mathcal{F}(k)) \neq 0$.  

Comment: Sorry. What I really mean is that $H^i(X, \mathcal{F}{k})=0$ for all $k$. Thank you for your answer. 

Comment: If $i = \dim \mathcal{F}$, then $H^i(X, \mathcal{F}(k))$ generally will not be zero for any $k \ll 0$.
$$\text{ }$$
Furthermore, if $\dim \mathcal{F} = 0$ (ie, a skyscraper sheaf), then the module $F$ is *never* finitely generated (unless it is zero).  The reason is we have non-zero infinitely negative degrees.  

Comment: What you can do is the following.  Choose a locally free resolution of $\mathcal{E}$ made up of $\oplus \mathcal{O}_X(m)$.  Now try to figure out if the $\Gamma_*$ of this resolution is still exact (at least in the low degrees you care about).  If it happens to still be exact, then you are are more or less fine... 